# Подключение к серверу по RDP

Tags: c#, .net, rdp

Хочу подключиться к серверу по rdp и столкнулся со следующим: если создать WinForms приложение, то все получается очень просто с использование AxMstscRdp..., но дело в том, что мне не нужно видеть удаленный рабочий стол, поэтому решил воспользоваться MsRdpClient, забиваю логин, пароль, IP, вызываю Connect() и ничего не происходит. Имею следующий код, который, по моим соображениям, должен работать (хотя бы rdp.connected должен быть не 0)

```
var rdp = new MSTSCLib.MsRdpClient8();
rdp.Server = "192.168.56.101";
rdp.UserName = "admin";
rdp.AdvancedSettings2.ClearTextPassword = "admin";
rdp.AdvancedSettings7.EnableCredSspSupport = true;
rdp.Connect();
```

Comment: может, что-то с версиями? Хотя по первому взгляду на код кажется, что он не совсем полный, так как обычно статьи для подключения к rdp были, по-моему, чуть побольше

Comment: Да я уже все версии перетыкал. Здесь минимум того, что нужно. Если кидать с tollbox на форму (а там AxRdPClient), то этих настроек достаточно, чтобы подключение прошло успешно.